# How to point domain B tot domain A without redirect in directadmin keeping HTTPS/SSL?

Tags: redirect, ssl, dns, directadmin

I'd like to point `bla.com` to `bla.org` without a redirect using directadmin on a shared hosting. How would I do this? Are there things to consider regarding SEO? I use a ALIAS pointer at the moment (Domain pointer -> Create as an Alias). However if I type https://bla.com it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to redirect from a https domain unless you provide a valid certificate for this domain in the first place. The certificate must match the domain you access even if you just want to redirect from it, i.e. `bla.com` in your case. It does not matter if this is a redirect on the HTTP level (i.e. code 301, 302) which changes the URL or if this is an alias (CNAME) or just address (A, AAAA record) at the DNS level in which case the URL does not change.